# How to determine why a hyperlink is not working?

Tags: javascript, html, css, hyperlink

I've created a new format of the main banner for my page. However, all the links except for the little preview picture on the right side isn't working and I have no idea why.

I'm a designer who's trying to do publishing at the same time so my knowledge for js is very limited but I deal with css and html quite well.

[Here is the link](https://www.afsmall.com/_wg/import/JS_mainBnr2.html)

```js
;
(function($) {

    $.fn.DB_tabArrowSlideMove2 = function(options) {
      var opt = {
        motionType: 'fade',
        motionSpeed: 300,
        autoRollingTime: 3000,
        videoRollingTime: 6000,
        arrowVisible: true,
        overRolling: false,
        random: false,
        yt_player: []
      };

      $.extend(opt, options);
      return this.each(function() {
          var $this = $(this);
          var $img = $this.find('.img');
          var $img_li = $img.find('> li');
          var $arrow = $this.find('.arrow');
          var $next = $this.find('.next');
          var $prev = $this.find('.prev');
          var $auto = $this.find('.auto');
          var len = $img_li.length;
          //console.log(len);
          var $btn = $this.find('.btn');
          if (len == 1) {
            $next.hide();
            $prev.hide();
            $btn.hide();
            return;
          }
          if ($btn.find('li').length == 0) {
            for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
              $btn.append('<li class=n' + (i + 1) + '><span>' + (i + 1) + '</span></li>');
            };
          };
          var $btn_li = $btn.find('> li');
          var current = 0;
          var oldCurrent = 0;
          var dir = 'next';
          var random = opt.random;
          if (random) {
            current = Math.floor(Math.random() * len);
            oldCurrent = current;
            dir = 'random';
          };

          var timerId = 0;
          var timer = 0;
          var autoPlay = true;
          var arrowOver = false;
          var imgWidth = $img_li.width();
          var imgHeight = $img_li.height();
          var overRolling = opt.overRolling;
          var arrowVisible = opt.arrowVisible;
          var motionType = opt.motionType;
          var motionSpeed = opt.motionSpeed;
          var autoRollingTime = opt.autoRollingTime;
          var videoRollingTime = opt.videoRollingTime;
          var mOver = false;

          //
          var $window = $(window);
          //var yt_player=opt.yt_player;
          var yt_length = yt_player.length;
          var yt_pos = {};
          var scrollTop = 0;
          if (yt_length) {
            //var $iframe=$this.find('iframe');  
            $iframe.each(function(index) {
              $(this).attr('data-no', index);
            });
            $window.scroll(function() {
              videoSoundByWinScroll();
            });
            var isMute = 1;
            videoSoundByWinScroll();

            function videoSoundByWinScroll() {
              yt_pos.start = $this.offset().top;
              yt_pos.height = $this.height()
              yt_pos.end = yt_pos.start + yt_pos.height
              scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
              if (scrollTop + $window.height() > yt_pos.start && scrollTop < yt_pos.end) {
                if (isMute == 0) {
                  var _iframe = $img_li.eq(current).find('iframe');
                  if (_iframe.length) {
                    var _no = _iframe.attr('data-no') * 1;
                    yt_player[_no].playVideo();
                  }
                  isMute = 1;
                  $this.mouseleave();
                }
              } else {
                if (isMute == 1) {
                  for (var i = 0; i < yt_length; i++) {
                    //console.log('멈춤'); 
                    yt_player[i].pauseVideo();
                  }
                  isMute = 0;
                  $this.mouseenter();
                }
              }
            }

          }

          init();

          function init() {
            setCss();
            setMouseEvent();
            setEnterFrame();
          };

          function setCss() {
            if (arrowVisible == false) {
              $arrow.hide();
              $auto.hide();
            };
            for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
              var _img = $img_li.eq(i);
              switch (motionType) {
                case 'x':
                  if (i == current) {
                    _img.css({
                      'left': 0,
                      'top': 0
                    });
                  } else {
                    _img.css({
                      'left': imgWidth * i,
                      'top': 0
                    });
                  }
                  break;
                case 'y':
                  if (i == current) {
                    _img.css({
                      'top': 0,
                      'left': 0
                    });
                  } else {
                    _img.css({
                      'top': imgHeight * i,
                      'left': 0
                    });
                  }
                  break;
                default:
                  _img.css({
                    'top': 0,
                    'left': 0
                  });
                  if (i == current) {
                    _img.show();
                  } else {
                    _img.hide();
                  };
              };
            };
            $btn_li.removeClass('on');
            $btn_li.eq(current).addClass('on');
            $btn_li.find('span').stop().css('width', 0);



            function setMouseEvent() {
              $this.bind('mouseenter', function() {
                mOver = true;
                if (overRolling == false && autoPlay == true) {
                  $btn_li.eq(current).find('span').stop();
                };
                if (arrowVisible == false) {
                  $arrow.show();
                  $auto.show();
                };
              });
              $this.bind('mouseleave', function() {
                mOver = false;
                if (overRolling == false && autoPlay == true) {
                  var time
                  if ($img_li.eq(current).find('iframe').length) {
                    time = videoRollingTime - videoRollingTime * $btn_li.eq(current).find('span').width() / $btn_li.eq(current).find('span').parent().width();
                  } else {
                    time = autoRollingTime - autoRollingTime * $btn_li.eq(current).find('span').width() / $btn_li.eq(current).find('span').parent().width();
                  }
                  //console.log('남은시간:'+time);
                  $btn_li.eq(current).find('span').animate({
                    'width': '100%'
                  }, time, 'linear');
                };
                if (arrowVisible == false) {
                  $arrow.hide();
                  $auto.hide();
                };
                if (random && (motionType != 'x' || motionType != 'y')) {
                  dir = 'random';
                }

              });
              $btn_li.bind('mouseenter', function() {
                var _index = $(this).index();
                if (_index > current) {
                  //dir='next';
                } else {
                  //dir='prev';
                };
                if (current != _index) {
                  current = _index;
                  setAnimation();
                };
              });

              $arrow.bind('mouseenter', function() {
                arrowOver = true;
              });
              $arrow.bind('mouseleave', function() {
                arrowOver = false;
              });
              $next.bind('click', function() {
                dir = 'next';
                changeCurrent();
              });
              $prev.bind('click', function() {
                dir = 'prev';
                changeCurrent();
              });

              $auto.bind('click', function() {
                if (autoPlay) {
                  autoPlay = false;
                  setReplace($auto.find('img'), 'src', '_on', '_off');
                } else {
                  autoPlay = true;
                  setReplace($auto.find('img'), 'src', '_off', '_on');
                };
              });

            };

            function changeCurrent() {
              if (autoPlay || arrowOver) {
                if (dir == 'next') {
                  current++;
                  if (current == len) {
                    current = 0
                  }
                } else if (dir == 'prev') {
                  current--;
                  if (current < 0) {
                    current = len - 1;
                  }
                  dir = "next";
                } else {
                  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    current = Math.floor(Math.random() * len);
                    if (oldCurrent != current) {
                      break;
                    }
                  }
                }
                //console.log(current);
                setAnimation();
              };
            };

            function setEnterFrame() {
              var rollingTime = 0;
              if (autoRollingTime > 0) {
                setInterval(function() {
                  // console.log(mOver,current,dir)
                  if (mOver == false || overRolling == true) {
                    timer++;
                    //console.log('현재동작중인:'+current)
                    //video
                    if ($img_li.eq(current).find('iframe').length) {
                      rollingTime = videoRollingTime;
                    } else {
                      rollingTime = autoRollingTime;
                    }
                    if (timer % (Math.ceil(rollingTime / 100)) == 0) {
                      changeCurrent();
                    }

                  }
                }, 100);
              };
            };


            $btn_li.removeClass('on');
            $btn_li.eq(current).addClass('on');
            $btn_li.find('span').stop().css('width', 0);
            if (mOver == false || overRolling == true) {


              function setReplace(_mc, _attr, _old, _new) {
                var str = _mc.attr(_attr);
                if (String(str).search(_old) != -1) {
                  _mc.attr(_attr, str.replace(_old, _new));
                };
              };
            });
        };
      })(jQuery);



    if ($iframe.length == 0) {

      $('.JS_mainBnr').DB_tabArrowSlideMove2({
        motionType: 'fade',
        motionSpeed: 600,
        autoRollingTime: 6000,
        arrowVisible: true,
        overRolling: false,
        random: false
      })
    }
```

```css
.JS_mainBnr {
  margin-top: -283px;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 369px/;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center
}

.JS_mainBnr .img {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
}

.JS_mainBnr .img:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

.JS_mainBnr .img li {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%!important;
  width: 5000px;
  height: auto;
  margin-left: -2500px;
  text-align: center;
}

.JS_mainBnr .img li a {
  width: 5000px;
  height: auto;
  display: inline-block
}

.JS_mainBnr .img li:first-child {
  z-index: 1;
}


/* Button */

.JS_mainBnr .btn {
  z-index: 3;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  letter-spacing: -4px;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%!important;
  width: 5000px;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: -2630px;
  text-align: center;
}

.JS_mainBnr .btn:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

.JS_mainBnr .btn li {
  position: relative;
  *zoom: 1;
  padding: 0 0;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.10);
  color: #333;
  font-size: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  transition: all .2s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease;
  width: 257px;
  margin-left: 60%;
}

.JS_mainBnr:hover .btn li {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}

.JS_mainBnr:hover .btn li img {
  opacity: 0.3
}

.JS_mainBnr .btn li.on {
  z-index: 1;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .9) color:#fff;
}

.JS_mainBnr:hover .btn li.on img {
  opacity: 1
}


/* Arrow */

.JS_mainBnr .prev {
  position: absolute;
  top: 285px;
  left: 515px;
  width: 21.5px;
  height: 30px;
  background: url('/_wg/img/_arrow/arrowL_50.gif') no-repeat 50% 50% rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-opacity: 0;
  transition: all .3s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
  background-size: 18px 27px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="JS_mainBnr">

  <ul class="img">

    <li>
      <a href="/_wg/import/afsmall.html"><img src="/_wg/img/JS_mainBnr/06P.jpg" alt=""></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/_wg/import/benefit.html"><img src="/_wg/img/JS_mainBnr/08O.jpg" alt=""></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/_wg/import/newcontent2.html"><img src="/_wg/img/JS_mainBnr/09J.jpg" alt=""></a>
    </li>

  </ul>

  <div id="outer">
    <ul class="btn">
      <li>
        <a href="/_wg/import/afsmall.html"><img src="/_wg/img/JS_mainBnr/01thumba.jpg" width="257px" height="105px"></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/_wg/import/benefit.html"><img src="/_wg/img/JS_mainBnr/02thumba.jpg" width="257px" height="105px"></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/_wg/import/newcontent2.html"><img src="/_wg/img/JS_mainBnr/03thumba.jpg" width="257px" height="105px"></a>
      </li>


    </ul>
  </div>

  <ul class="DB_dir">
    <span class="arrow prev"></span>
    <span class="arrow next"></span>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You've posted way too much code, and most of it looks like it's unrelated to the question, like all the stuff about animation and playing YouTube videos. Please reduce this to a [mcve] that just illustrates the problem.

Comment: What could `onPlayerReady` and `setAnimation` have to do with following hyperlinks? Try removing things that don't seem to be related to links, and see if the problem remains.

Comment: How could you write all of this without really understanding it?

Comment: Now the braces aren't matching in the JavaScript, and it's not obvious where the missing close braces go.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

```
.JS_mainBnr .btn {
z-index: 3;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 50%;
margin-left: 370px;
```

}

.JS_mainBnr .btn li {
    margin-left: 60% } /*<< DELETE*/